# Correct query for count on elasticsearch php library

Tags: php, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I'm using the  [php library for elasticsearch](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php) And I'm triying to get a count from a search, using the count method, to avoid fetching all the results. But seems that I'm not using the correct format or something when querying the elasticsearch server.

Here is what I'm doing

```
        $hosts = ['localhost:9200'];
        $client = ClientBuilder::create()
        ->setHosts($hosts)
        ->build();


        $params = [
        'index' => 'logstash-*',
        'type'  => 'INFO',
        'body'  => [
            'query' => [
                'bool' => [
                    "should" => [
                        ["term" => ["tags" => "producer"]],
                        ["term" => ["tags" => "statistics"]],
                        ["term" => ["message" => "view"]],
                        ["term" => ["context.id" => 1]]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];


$response = $client->search($params); // was returning all the results too, I was wrong
$response = $client->count($params); // return a count of all my documents in elasticsearch instance, that's wrong
```

FIXED thanx to @Val i set the minimun should match to 4 and it works!

```
    array (size=4)
  'took' => int 14
  'timed_out' => boolean false
  '_shards' => 
    array (size=3)
      'total' => int 10
      'successful' => int 10
      'failed' => int 0
  'hits' => 
    array (size=3)
      'total' => int 11
      'max_score' => float 7.852423
      'hits' => 
        array (size=10)
          0 => 
            array (size=5)
              ...
          1 => 
            array (size=5)
              ...
          2 => 
            array (size=5)
              ...
          3 => 
            array (size=5)
              ...
          4 => 
            array (size=5)
              ...
          5 => 
            array (size=5)
              ...
          6 => 
            array (size=5)
              ...
          7 => 
            array (size=5)
              ...
          8 => 
            array (size=5)
              ...
          9 => 
            array (size=5)
              ...
array (size=2)
  'count' => int 11
  '_shards' => 
    array (size=3)
      'total' => int 10
      'successful' => int 10
      'failed' => int 0
```

How can I get the correct count for the query?

Comment: What happens if you add `"minimum_should_match" => 1` in your `bool` query?

Comment: @Val it returns the same count, a bad one with all the documents on the elasticsearch instance

{
array (size=2)
  'count' => int 6539
  '_shards' => 
    array (size=3)
      'total' => int 10
      'successful' => int 10
      'failed' => int 0
}

Comment: Can you update your question with the result you get from each call, please?

Comment: I updated the question. I was wrong and it was the query wich was incomplete. The search was returning all the documents too and not only the 4 I was looking for :) it was just a coincidence. Thanks @Val

Comment: Ok, glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited the question with the correct answer. 
The final query is:

```
$params = [
    'index' => 'logstash-*',
    'type'  => 'INFO',
    'body'  => [
        'query' => [
            'bool' => [
                "should" => [
                    ["term" => ["tags" => "producer"]],
                    ["term" => ["tags" => "statistics"]],
                    ["term" => ["message" => "view"]],
                    ["term" => ["context.id" => 1]]
                ],
               "minimum_should_match" => 4
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

Comment: But if all term queries should match, you're probably better off using `bool/must` or if you are on ES 2 `bool/filter`